# the ArrayList size is zero outside of the loop

Tags: java, android, arraylist

i'm using ParseObject for getting some data,every thing works good on the loop but outside of loop it seems The list will be deleted and the size is zero,im wondering about that!help me please

```
public class frag1 extends Fragment {


public frag1() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

String TAG="val";
public static ArrayList<getData> data;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frag1, container, false);
    data=new ArrayList<getData>();

    ListView list=(ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(new listAdapter());

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("mPlayDataBase");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> obj, ParseException e) {

            if (e == null) {
                for(ParseObject po:obj){

                    String st1=(String) po.getString("name");
                    String st2=(String) po.getString("family");
                    String st3=(String) po.getString("phone");

                    data.add(new getData(st1,st2,st3));
                    Log.v(TAG,"size "+ data.size());//the size here is 3 and this is right
                }

            } else {
                Log.v(TAG,"WRONG VALUE");

            }
        }
    });


    Log.v(TAG,"size2  "+ data.size());//the problem is here,size is 0


    return v;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `query.findInBackground()` executes the code asynchronously, so it will trigger the call without waiting for the fetching to be completed and then directly continue executing this line

`Log.v(TAG,"size2  "+ data.size());//the problem is here,size is 0`

Then when fetching is completed the `done()` is called and then you can see that it has 3 elements,

**So how to solve this?**

move your code into `done()` or put it in a function and call that function in `done()`

Hope this helps!

Comment: How can we access outside that arraylist ,if we add elements in parse query in for loop ?